# stored procedures with sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

How can I call stored procedures of sql server with sqlAlchemy?

Answer (score 25):

Engines and Connections have an `execute()` method you can use for arbitrary sql statements, and so do Sessions. For example:

```
results = sess.execute('myproc ?, ?', [param1, param2])
```

You can use `outparam()` to create output parameters if you need to (or for bind parameters use `bindparam()` with the `isoutparam=True` option)

Comment: This is not database-agnostic. Use `sqlalchemy.sql.text` instead.

Comment: BTW you need to `sess.execute('SET NOCOUNT ON')` if you want to access the rows returned by the stored procedure in MS SQL Server.

You can do that in one execute call: `results = sess.execute('SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC myproc ?, ?; SET NOCOUNT OFF', [param1, param2])`.

Comment: This is an old thread so, maybe this is something that has changed in newer versions of sqlalchemy, but I had to use a dictionary instead of a list for the parameters and use ":param_name" in the raw sql instead of "?".

So, the example above becomes: `sess.execute('myproc :p1, :p2', {'p1': 'value1', 'p2': 'value2'})`

Comment: Also check Denis Otkidach answer(and comments part)

Comment: We had a case where the run in a standard connection failed, but succeeded when run in a transaction: `with engine.begin() as conn: ...`

Comment: @Steven how can we use output param ? Example, stmt.bindparams(bindparam("isTrue", type_=bool, isoutparam=True))
            result = conn.execute(stmt, {
            'id': mydata.id,
            'name': mydata.name}) How to add output param in result?

Answer (score 18):

*context*: I use flask-sqlalchemy with MySQL and without ORM-mapping. Usually, I use:

```
# in the init method
_db = SqlAlchemy(app)

#... somewhere in my code ...
_db.session.execute(query)
```

---

Calling stored procedures is not supported out of the box: the `callproc` is not generic, but specific to the mysql connector.

For stored procedures **without out params**, it is possible to execute a query like

```
_db.session.execute(sqlalchemy.text("CALL my_proc(:param)"), param='something')
```

as usual. Things get more complicated when you have **out params**...

---

One way to use out params is to access the underlying connector is through `engine.raw_connection()`. For example:

```
conn = _db.engine.raw_connection()
# do the call. The actual parameter does not matter, could be ['lala'] as well
results = conn.cursor().callproc('my_proc_with_one_out_param', [0])
conn.close()   # commit
print(results) # will print (<out param result>)
```

This is nice since we are able to access the out parameter, **BUT this connection is not managed by the flask session**. This means that it won't be committed/aborted as with the other managed queries... (problematic only if your procedure has side-effect).

Finally, I ended up doing this:

```py
# do the call and store the result in a local mysql variabl
# the name does not matter, as long as it is prefixed by @
_db.session.execute('CALL my_proc_with_one_out_param(@out)')
# do another query to get back the result
result = _db.session.execute('SELECT @out').fetchone()
```

The `result` will be a tuple with one value: the out param. This is not ideal, but the least dangerous: if another query fails during the session, the procedure call will be aborted (rollback) as well.

Comment: Is it possible to map the results to a class?

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to call a stored procedure in MySQL using SQLAlchemy is by using `callproc` method of `Engine.raw_connection()`. `call_proc` will require the procedure name and parameters required for the stored procedure being called.

```
def call_procedure(function_name, params):
       connection = cloudsql.Engine.raw_connection()
       try:
           cursor = connection.cursor()
           cursor.callproc(function_name, params)
           results = list(cursor.fetchall())
           cursor.close()
           connection.commit()
           return results
       finally:
           connection.close()
```

Comment: It works for more than MySQL.  I can personally confirm that Postgres works out of the box as well.  See the official SQL Alchemy docs supporting this answer: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html

Comment: Is it possible to map results to the ORM class and use it with the where clause?

Answer (score 12):

Just execute procedure object created with `func`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
print engine.execute(func.upper('abc')).scalar() # Using engine
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
print session.execute(func.upper('abc')).scalar() # Using session
```

Comment: Worked for me, Elegant and simple way to call stored procedures.Official notes _The :data:`.func` construct has only limited support for calling
        standalone "stored procedures", especially those with special
        parameterization concerns.
        See the section :ref:`stored_procedures` for details on how to use
        the DBAPI-level ``callproc()`` method for fully traditional stored
        procedures._

Code for people like me :`session.execute(func.your_proc_name(param1, param2))`

Comment: Does this work for user-generated stored procedures? I am getting an error that my function is not a built-in procedure.

Answer (score 9):

Supposing you already have session created with sessionmaker(), you can use following function:

```
def exec_procedure(session, proc_name, params):
    sql_params = ",".join(["@{0}={1}".format(name, value) for name, value in params.items()])
    sql_string = """
        DECLARE @return_value int;
        EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[{proc_name}] {params};
        SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value;
    """.format(proc_name=proc_name, params=sql_params)

    return session.execute(sql_string).fetchall()
```

Now you can execute your stored procedure 'MyProc' with parameters simply like that:

```
params = {
    'Foo': foo_value,
    'Bar': bar_value
}
exec_procedure(session, 'MyProc', params)
```

Comment: This seems vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: This indeed is vulnerable. It is better to pass named arguments with `execute(sql_string, params=...)` to let the engine escape the argument values. The answer by @Profpatsch does that already.

Comment: How would I collect an output parameter with this? ie, my statement is: 
`EXEC dbo.next_rowid 'dbo', 'workorder_feature', @id OUTPUT;` how do I get the id?

Answer (score 4):

Out of desperate need for a project of mine, I wrote a function that handles Stored Procedure calls.

Here you go:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sql

def execute_db_store_procedure(database, types, sql_store_procedure, *sp_args):
    """ Execute the store procedure and return the response table.

    Attention: No injection checking!!!

    Does work with the CALL syntax as of yet (TODO: other databases).

    Attributes:
        database            -- the database
        types               -- tuple of strings of SQLAlchemy type names.
                               Each type describes the type of the argument
                               with the same number.
                               List: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/types.html
        sql_store_procudure -- string of the stored procedure to be executed
        sp_args             -- arguments passed to the stored procedure
    """
    if not len(types) == len(sp_args):
        raise ValueError("types tuple must be the length of the sp args.")

    # Construch the type list for the given types
    # See
    # http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=expression.text#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text
    # sp_args (and their types) are numbered from 0 to len(sp_args)-1
    type_list = [sql.sql.expression.bindparam(
                    str(no), type_=getattr(sql.types, typ)())
                        for no, typ in zip(range(len(types)), types)]

    try:
        # Adapts to the number of arguments given to the function
        sp_call = sql.text("CALL `%s`(%s)" % (
                sql_store_procedure,
                ", ".join([":%s" % n for n in range(len(sp_args))])),
            bindparams=type_list
        )
        #raise ValueError("%s\n%s" % (sp_call, type_list))
        with database.engine.begin() as connection:
            return connection.execute(
                sp_call,
                # Don't do this at home, kids...
                **dict((str(no), arg)
                    for (no, arg) in zip(range(len(sp_args)), sp_args)))
    except sql.exc.DatabaseError:
        raise
```

It works with the CALL syntax, so MySQL should work as expected. MSSQL uses EXEC instead of call and a little differennt syntax, I guess. So making it server agnostic is up to you but shouldn’t be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround:

```
query = f'call Procedure ("{@param1}", "{@param2}", "{@param3}")'    
sqlEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(jdbc)
conn = sqlEngine.connect() 
df = pd.read_sql(query,conn,index_col=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a stored procedure for postgresql with following signature -

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE inc_run_count(
        _host text,
        _org text,
        _repo text,
        _rule_ids text[]
    )
```

After quite a few error and trial, I found this is how to call the procedure from python3.

```
    def update_db_rule_count(rule_ids: List[str], host: str, org: str, repo: str):
        param_dict = {"host": host, "org": org, "repo": repo, "rule_ids": f'{{ {",".join(rule_ids)} }}'}


        with sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=ro_engine) as analytics_db:
            analytics_db.execute('call inc_run_count(:host, :org, :repo, :rule_ids)', param_dict)
            analytics_db.commit()
```

Comment: What is `AnaltycisSession()`? Can you explain it more?

Comment: Updated the answer to make it clearer. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a terrible workaround, but I stumbled by accident onto this solution.

If you're using 'mssql+pyodbc' `cursor.callproc()` doesn't seem to exist. Additionally if you try to separate your queries into separate executions—for example declaring an out paramater—caling the execution step fails to find the value you specified.

However

```py
rawconn = engine.raw_connection
try:
  cursor = rawconn.cursor()
  cursor.execute(
    f'''
      DECLARE @outstring nvarchar(max)
      EXECUTE [dbo].[stored_proc] @param1={param1}, @param2={param2}, @outstring=@outstring OUTPUT
      SELECT @outstring as [outstring]
    '''
  )
  #results = list(cursor.fetchall())
  cursor.close()
  rawconn.commit()
finally:
  rawconn.close()
```

very nearly works. The Stored procedure gets called; unfortunately the `cursor.fetchall()` returns a "ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query" exception.

The good news is that in this case, I only want a single string response, I'm not after a table of values. So if your stored procedure has a `PRINT @outstring` statement in it, the string can be found in the `cursor.messages` list. It's not perfect, `cursor.messages[0][1]` returns "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL SERVER][SQL Server]<actual printed statement>" and the newlines for some reason are `\r` alone like it was still the 80s. But it's close enough for me.

Only other downside is that `cursor.messages` is a DB API extension. It works for mssql, but I don't know what other databases support it.