# Python sqlalchemy and mySQL stored procedure always returns 0 (out param only)

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I am trying to get the `ROW_COUNT()` from a MySQL stored procedure into python.

here is what I got, but I don't know what I am missing.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_refresh_mytable(
    OUT row_count INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE exit handler for SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
        END;
    DECLARE exit handler for SQLWARNING
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
        END;
    DECLARE exit handler FOR NOT FOUND
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
        END;

    START TRANSACTION;
    DELETE FROM mytable;

    INSERT INTO mytable
    (
          col1
        , col2
    )
    SELECT
          col1
        , col2
    FROM othertable
    ;
    SET row_count =  ROW_COUNT();
    COMMIT;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

If I call this in via normal SQL like follows I get the correct row_count of the insert operation (e.g. 26 rows inserted):

```
CALL sp_refresh_mytable(@rowcount);
select @rowcount as t;
-- output: 26
```

Then in python/mysqlalchemy:

```
def call_procedure(engine, function_name, params=None):
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        result = cursor.callproc('sp_refresh_mytable', [0])
        ## try result outputs
        resultfetch = cursor.fetchone()
        logger.info(result)
        logger.info(result[0])
        logger.info(resultfetch)
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        logger.info(f"Running procedure {function_name} success!")
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Running procedure {function_name} failed!")
        logger.exception(e)
        return None
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

So I tried logging different variations of getting the out value, but it is always 0 or None.

```
[INFO] db_update    [0]
[INFO] db_update    0
[INFO] db_update    None
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546157/5320906) help?

Comment: thanks @snakecharmerb, very good info, but there is no info on sqlalchemy unfortunately...

Comment: The `raw_connection` is a DB-API connection; there's no SQLAlchemy  involved here.

Comment: It says: "Getting results ... depends on ... the python package used to make the call". So sqlalchemy package is not mentioned there. But with some trial and error of those solutions and another one from another thread, I figured out two working solution, which I will post in my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546157/5320906) I found the following solution that worked for me.

a) Working solution using `engine.raw_connection()` and `cursor.callproc`:

```
def call_procedure(engine, function_name):
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.callproc(function_name, [0])
        cursor.execute(f"""SELECT @_{function_name}_0""")
        results = cursor.fetchone() ## returns a tuple e.g. (285,)
        rows_affected = results[0]
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
        logger.info(f"Running procedure {function_name} success!")
        return rows_affected
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Running procedure {function_name} failed!")
        logger.exception(e)
        return None
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

And with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50001721/7183482) I found this solution also:

b) Instead of using a raw connection, this worked as well:

```
def call_procedure(engine, function_name, params=None):
    try:
        with engine.begin() as db_conn:
            db_conn.execute(f"""CALL {function_name}(@out)""")
            results = db_conn.execute('SELECT @out').fetchone() ## returns a tuple e.g. (285,)
            rows_affected = results[0]
        logger.debug(f"Running procedure {function_name} success!")
        return rows_affected
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Running procedure {function_name} failed!")
        logger.exception(e)
        return None
    finally:
        if db_conn: db_conn.close()
```

If there are any advantages or drawbacks of using one of these methods over the other, please let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add another piece of code, since I was trying to get `callproc` to work (using sqlalchemy) with **multiple in- and out-params**.

For this case I went with the `callproc` method using a raw connection [solution b) in my previous answer], since this functions accepts params as a list.

It could probably be done more elegantly or more pythonic in some parts, but it was mainly for getting it to work and I will probably create a function from this so I can use it for generically calling a SP with multiple in and out params.

I included comments in the code below to make it easier to understand what is going on.

In my case I decided to put the out-params in a dict so I can pass it along to the calling app in case I need to react to the results. Of course you could also include the in-params which could make sense for error logging maybe.

```
## some in params
function_name   = 'sp_upsert'
in_param1       = 'my param 1'
in_param2       = 'abcdefg'
in_param3       = 'some-name'
in_param4       = 'some display name'
in_params = [in_param1, in_param1, in_param1, in_param1]
## out params
out_params = [
     'out1_row_count'
    ,'out2_row_count'
    ,'out3_row_count'
    ,'out4_row_count_ins'
    ,'out5_row_count_upd'
]
params = copy(in_params)
## adding the outparams as integers from out_params indices
params.extend([i for i, x in enumerate(out_params)])
## the params list will look like
## ['my param 1', 'abcdefg', 'some-name', 'some display name', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
logger.info(params)
## build query to get results from callproc (including in and out params)
res_qry_params = []
for i in range(len(params)):
    res_qry_params.append(f"@_{function_name}_{i}")
res_qry = f"SELECT  {', '.join(res_qry_params)}"
## the query to fetch the results (in and out params) will look like
## SELECT  @_sp_upsert_0, @_sp_upsert_1, @_sp_upsert_2, @_sp_upsert_3, @_sp_upsert_4, @_sp_upsert_5, @_sp_upsert_6, @_sp_upsert_7, @_sp_upsert_8
logger.info(res_qry)
try:
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    ## calling the sp
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc(function_name, params)
    ## get the results (includes in and out params), the 0/1 in the end are the row_counts from the sp
    ## fetchone is enough since all results come as on result record like
    ## ('my param 1', 'abcdefg', 'some-name', 'some display name', 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
    cursor.execute(res_qry)
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    logger.info(results)
    ## adding just the out params to a dict
    res_dict = {}
    for i, element in enumerate(out_params):
        res_dict.update({
            element: results[i + len(in_params)]
            })
    ## the result dict in this case only contains the out param results and will look like
    ## { 'out1_row_count': 1,
    ##   'out2_row_count': 0,
    ##   'out3_row_count': 1,
    ##   'out4_row_count_ins': 1,
    ##   'out5_row_count_upd': 0}
    logger.info(pformat(res_dict, indent=2, sort_dicts=False))
    cursor.close()
    connection.commit()
    logger.debug(f"Running procedure {function_name} success!")
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Running procedure {function_name} failed!")
    logger.exception(e)
```

Just to complete the picture, here is a shortened version of my stored procedure. After BEGIN I declare some error handlers I set the out params to default 0, otherwise they could also return as NULL/None if not set by the procedure (e.g. because no insert was made):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_upsert(
    IN in_param1 VARCHAR(32),
    IN in_param2 VARCHAR(250),
    IN in_param3 VARCHAR(250),
    IN in_param4 VARCHAR(250),
    OUT out1_row_count INTEGER,
    OUT out2_row_count INTEGER,
    OUT out3_row_count INTEGER,
    OUT out4_row_count_ins INTEGER,
    OUT out5_row_count_upd INTEGER
)
BEGIN
    -- declare variables, do NOT declare the out params here!
    DECLARE dummy INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    
    -- declare error handlers (e.g. continue handler for not found)
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET dummy = 1;
    
    -- set out params defaulting to 0
    SET out1_row_count = 0;
    SET out2_row_count = 0;
    SET out3_row_count = 0;
    SET out4_row_count_ins = 0;
    SET out5_row_count_upd = 0;

    -- do inserts and updates and set the outparam variables accordingly
    INSERT INTO some_table ...;
    SET out1_row_count = ROW_COUNT();

    -- commit if no errors
    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```