# How to call MySQL stored procedure in FastAPI?

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy, fastapi

This is the  `models.py` used to create a table:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String,Boolean,BigInteger,Date
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from database import database


Base=database.Base


class country_table(Base):
    __tablename__='country'
    CountryId = Column(Integer(),  primary_key=True, index=True)
    CountryName = Column(String(25))
    IsActive = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    CreatedDate = Column(Date())
    CreatedBy = Column(BigInteger())
    UpdatedDate = Column(Date())
    UpdatedBy = Column(BigInteger())
    Is_delete = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

This is the `database.py` that is creating an engine and processing a table:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://root:1234@localhost:3306/property_valuation'

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

I want to connect with a stored procedure and call the procedure in FastAPI.
Where do I want to call and how can call?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stored procedures with sqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563738/stored-procedures-with-sqlalchemy)