# Execute Stored Procedure with SQL Alchemy Connection

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I want to execute a stored procedure using an SQL Alchemy Connection. I get no errors during execution, but no changes are reflected on the database. If I run the stored procedure directly on my Azure SQL Server, I get the expected results (which are updating a table).

I tried running just the procedure and get this:
[image]

Any ideas on why it is not working?

I am also open to other ideas! I am trying to execute my stored procedure after upserting a table.

Comment: @python_user engine = create_engine(conn_str, fast_executemany=True)
                metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
                session = engine.connect()
                return session, engine, metadata

Comment: @python_user I get  'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: try this: `conn.execute("""CALL sp_updateActivityInsertDate();""")`

Some more examples are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563738/stored-procedures-with-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended approach for current versions of SQLAlchemy is to use a *context manager* (`with` block) to `begin()` the transaction. When the context manager exits the transaction will automatically be committed unless an error has occurred:

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("EXEC my_stored_procedure")
```

Bonus tip: Naming stored procedures with an `sp_` prefix is discouraged because it can lead to confusion with SQL Server's built-in "system procedures". More details here:

https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is the only thing that worked for me. And thanks for the info on naming stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

use '`conn.commit()`' to commit changes to the db
then use '`conn.close()`' to end the connection

Implementation:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite3')
conn.execute(f"insert into Users Values('email', 'password')")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```