# how to run the .sql file in sqlalchemy in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I created a postgres function and saved in a file called `get_data.sql`

```
    create or replace function getalldata(entryDate TIMESTAMP, exitDate TIMESTAMP) RETURNS SETOF employee AS $$
    BEGIN
            begin     -- try
                    select employee.name, dept.name
                    from employee 
                    join dept on employee.dept_id=dept.id
                    where  employee.name='Kumar' and 
                    employee.timestamp>=entryDate and employee.timestamp<=exitDate;
            exception when others then 

                raise notice 'The transaction is in an uncommittable state. '
                             'Transaction was rolled back';

                raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
            end ; -- try..catch
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I run this sql file in sqlalchemy

```
    try:
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
        connection = engine.connect()
        with open('get_data.sql', 'r') as file:
            procedure_sql = file.read()

        procedure_sql = text(procedure_sql)

        results = connection.execute(
                procedure_sql,
                {'entryDate':start_datetime, 'exitDate':end_datetime}
            )
        results = list(results.fetchall())
    except Exception as e:
        print('error', e)
```

But I got this error

> error This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

How to solve this issue, and which causes this error

Comment: Installation (creation) of the function is something you do only once. After that you can use the function by using the correct SQL statement and function name. That's missing in your code

Comment: @FrankHeikens, could you please guide me in that installation and calling the function name

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34218558/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: I run the function in the psql and  used the 'select getalldata()' query using engine commmand in sqlalchemy by running raw query

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are trying to fetch rows after the result set has been closed.

To resolve this issue, you should fetch the rows immediately after executing the query and before closing the result set.

Try this out:

```
results = connection.execute("Your SQL Query").fetchall()
```

Comment: I used this pattern, thanks for sharing